# any way to override an editor template in Kendo Grid using MVC wrappers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid using incell editing mode that includes an integer column. As with most integer columns, when I add a new row it automatically adds a 0 value and uses the IntegerTextBox editor template. However, because the user doesn't want to ever use the rollers and doesn't want to have to backspace over the 0 before setting their value they have requested that we disable the template so it behaves like any other editor. I know I can create a shared editor template that essentially is just a @Html.EditorFor(m => m) but that seems like a waste. Is there a way to simply tell the grid or model that I don't want to use an editor template? Can I give it a hint to a template that doesn't exist?

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Column Order")]
    [Range(1, 99)]
    public int ColumnOrder { get; set; }
```

**Edit:** 
I know I can create another shared template (call it ColumnOrder.cshtml, for example) and make that template a simple `@EditorFor(m => m)`, then use `[UIHInt("ColumnOrder")]` but that seems like a waste when all I want to do is tell it NOT to use the Integer template.

Comment: you can have EditorTemplates in Views/Shared and use those for these editors

Answer (score 2):

Can't you make the datatype of the column int?

```
    public int? ColumnOrder { get; set; }
```